# I saw this piece of code online and im not sure why its not working when i use it

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and this is the first roadblock that I've stumbled upon. I saw this piece of code in a TikTok video. I'm confused; I didn't know you can have colorful outputs in VS Code! Do I have to import a file or something to be able to use the colors? I don't really understand what the `back.Red` or the `Fore.YELLOW` functions mean, it would be appreciated if someone could explain. Thank you!

```
colours = [
Back.RED, Back.GREEN,
Back.CYAN, Back.MAGENTA
      ]
yel = Fore.YELLOW 
emojis = ['', '', '']

while True :
    for n in emojis:
        for back in colours:
            print(back+yel, end ='')
            print('  coding!', n )
            sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: back = background of text. Fore = foreground of text.

Comment: What does your questions description have to do with its title?

Comment: also you need to import `from colorama import Back,Fore` & 
`import time`

Comment: @BuddyBob well, he needs to `from time import sleep` to be precise

Comment: That's true good spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Summary

This piece of code is using an external library called [Colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama). You need to import this library before using it. More information about colored outputs in Python can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332860/14363557).

The `Fore` and `Back` are constants/functions supplied by Colorama, which when you surround a string with them and `print` it to the terminal, give the string a colored FOREground or BACKground.

### The Details

```
colours = [
    Back.RED, Back.GREEN,
    Back.CYAN, Back.MAGENTA
]
yel = Fore.YELLOW 
emojis = ['', '', '']
```

This creates a list containing background color constants provided by Colorama, sets a variable containing the yellow foreground color constant, and creates a list of emoji strings.

```
while True :
    for n in emojis:
        for back in colours:
            print(back+yel, end ='')
            print('  coding!', n )
            sleep(0.5)
```

This loops forever inside a `while True`, and each time, iterates through the emoji list. And for each iteration of the emoji list, iterates through the background constant list. And for each constant, it prints a string surrounded by a background color constant, the yellow foreground color constant, the word "  coding!", and the emoji. Then it pauses half a second.